# How to connect SSH.NET in MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, ssh, ssh.net

I'm using this SSH.NET client https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/ and MongoDB C# latest client. As per https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1142 i'm trying to inject SSHStream into MongoDB Client settings. My SSH connection is successful. But i'm not able to establish a connection to MongoDB through SSH.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings
        {
            ClusterConfigurator = cb =>
            {
                cb.RegisterStreamFactory(CustomStreamFac);
            }   
        };
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        IMongoDatabase db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("testdb");
        var collections = db.ListCollections();
    }

    public static IStreamFactory CustomStreamFac(IStreamFactory istreamfac)
    {

        Stream stream = istreamfac.CreateStream();
        return istreamfac;
    }

public static class Extension
{
    public static Stream CreateStream(this IStreamFactory isf)
    {
        ConnectionInfo conn = new ConnectionInfo(hostname, port, username, new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(username, new PrivateKeyFile(keyfile, password)));
        SshClient cli = new SshClient(conn);
        cli.Connect();
        ShellStream shellStream = null;
        shellStream = cli.CreateShellStream("Command", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024);            
        return shellStream;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) Can you connect to `hostname:port` using any SSH client running on the same machine as your C# code? 2) Do you have any reason to believe the `CreateShellStream` should be able to cooperate with MongoDB? I didn't find any evidence for that in the Jira link.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, i'm able to connect to the SSH server using this `host:port`. And no they haven't mentioned anything about `CreateShellStream`. I'm not sure it'll coperate but I only see this option to convert the sshclient as stream to be passed on to `IStreamFactory`

Comment: So start by creating a simple console application that only ssh to that `hostname:port`. If it does not connect, show us also a log file from your SSH client for comparison.  -- Your immediate problem has nothing to do with MongoDB. -- Also you didn't confirm that you run your SSH client on the same machine as your C# code. - How do you run your C# btw?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I do not have a problem with SSH connection. My SSH is hosted in Amazon EC2 and `cli.Connect();` creates a successful connection. What is the SSH client you are referring to? My C# console(SSH.NET) is the client I use. To confirm the SSH communication I used RoboMongo as an additional SSH client on the same machine where my C# code is and established a communication.

Comment: So where do you get *"connection refused exception"*? Not in SSH code? Do you get it in MongoDB code?

Comment: Yes in MongoDB.

Comment: OK, so please say that in your question! Ideally you should include exception stacktrace (and exact error message)  + What is `"Command"`? Do you have that literally in your code? Or do execute any actual command?

Comment: You didn't answer my question about `"Command"`. + Would you explain what do you want your code to do? Can you connect to your database using any tool from the machine, where you run the C# code? If you can, how do do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can start the SSH client using below code.

```
ConnectionInfo conn = new ConnectionInfo(SSHServerHost, SSHServerPort,SSHServerUserName, new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(SSHServerUserName, new PrivateKeyFile(PrivateKeyPath,SSHServerPassword)));
SshClient = new SshClient(conn);
SshClient.Connect();
ForwardedPortLocal forwardedPortLocal = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1",5477,MongoDBHost, MongoDBPort);
SshClient.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPortLocal);
forwardedPortLocal.Start();
```

Now SSH client will forward localhost port 5477 to remote MongoDB database server.

MongoClient can be used to communicate with MongoDB Server with host as localhost and port as 5477.

Refer below code snippet to connect with MongoDB Server.

```
MongoConnection connection = new MongoConnection();
MongoDBClientConnection clientConnection = new MongoDBClientConnection(){MongoDBClient = new MongoClient( MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings
            {
                Server = new MongoServerAddress(localhost, 5477)                
            };)}        
connection.MongoDBServer = clientConnection.MongoDBClient.GetServer();
connection.MongoDBServer.Connect();
```

Above code will connect with MongoDB Server using SSH tunnel.

Comment: This works!! But it does not follow the SSH stream factory implementation inside the MongoClient as said here, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-768. Any explanation on this?