# Connecting from home Windows computer or Windows EC2 server to a Ubuntu MongoDB EC2 server via SSH and port forwarding?

Tags: c#, mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, portforwarding

I have two AWS EC2 instances:

1. Windows Server which will handle user requests for data.
2. Ubuntu server with MongoDB database on it to be accessed and manipulated by Windows Server.

I am attempting to write a program in C# .NET that will be able to connect to the Ubuntu server and its MongoDB when run from my local computer or from the Windows Server.

I am using [Renci SSH.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Core.Renci.SshNet/) and the standard [MongoDB driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver). The MongoDB driver operation is explained [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/getting_started/quick_tour/). For networking, I found one old guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57036727/10305478) which helped me get part way. I have so far:

```
string SSHServerUserName = "ubuntu";
string SSHServerHost = "x.xx.xxx.xxx"; //public IP of ubuntu server as per AWS
PrivateKeyFile keyFile = new PrivateKeyFile(@"H:\MongoDB.pem", "filePass"); //mongo server AWS keyfile
PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod = new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(SSHServerUserName, keyFile);

ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(SSHServerHost, SSHServerUserName, authenticationMethod); //uses DefaultPort = 22

SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
//sshClient.ErrorOccurred += delegate { Debug.WriteLine("SSH ERROR OCCURRED"); };
//sshClient.HostKeyReceived += delegate { Debug.WriteLine("SSH HOST KEY RECEIVED"); };
sshClient.Connect();

if (sshClient.IsConnected) {

    string MongoDBHost = "xx.xx.xx.xx"; // **PRIVATE IP OF UBUNTU AWS EC2? 
    uint MongoDBPort = 27017;

    ForwardedPortLocal forwardedPortLocal = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 5477, MongoDBHost, MongoDBPort);

    //forwardedPortLocal.Exception += delegate { Debug.WriteLine("FORWARDED PORT LOCAL EXCEPTION"); };
    //forwardedPortLocal.RequestReceived += delegate { Debug.WriteLine("FORWARDED PORT REQUEST RECEIVED"); };

    sshClient.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPortLocal);
    forwardedPortLocal.Start();

    MongoClientSettings mongoSettings = new MongoClientSettings();
    mongoSettings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 5477); //IS THIS RIGHT?
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoSettings);

    var iMongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase("test");

    var profiles = iMongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("profiles");

    Debug.WriteLine("GOT THE COLLECTION:"); //debugs out okay...

    var document = new BsonDocument {
        { "name", "userName" },
        { "type", "newUser" },
        { "count", 1 },
        { "info", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "x", 203 },
            { "y", 102 }
        } }
    };

    profiles.InsertOne(document); //reports time out exception if using try/catch

    Debug.Write("ATTEMPTED TO INSERT ONE");
}
```

I am getting `sshClient.IsConnected()` as true. However, I do not know if my forwarded port is working correctly or to what extent it is or isn't connecting to the Mongo Database. I can see from MongoDB Compass (GUI database navigator) nothing is being inserted, and from a try catch statement I can receive the exception that the MongoDB driver times out on the `InsertOne` command.

***Questions:***

- How do I test the Forwarded Local Port? I see `FORWARDED PORT REQUEST RECEIVED` outputs but don't know if they're working.
- Is the MongoDB server code (IPs, ports, "localhost") correct for this configuration? How do I test to see if it has connected properly to the database?
- What is going wrong in the above?

This is my first database and EC2 configuration. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't really understand the above code. Try configuring tls as I mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518922/problem-with-connect-to-mongodb-use-tls-certifications/73519205#73519205

Comment: with only .net driver

Comment: Thanks dododo but I am not even using TLS. I have TLS/SSL turned off on the MongoDB. There is no current username or password. When I connect through Mongo Compass those options are all "Off" and I can still connect. So in my case, I need to make an SSH connection to EC2 by keyfile (done), then need to forward a port and have MongoClient connect through it. I think that's the only way. But it won't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please include the mongod.conf file contents (the database server configuration file on the Ubuntu host)?  Usually found at /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: I believe out of the box installations of MongoDB set bindIp to 127.0.0.1, which means onlly connections on localhost will be accepted.  To open this up to the world (not safe, but useful for testing) set bindIp to 0.0.0.0.  If testing shows it works you will need to secure it by identifying the ip address which the port forwarding is using.

Comment: Thanks barry. Unfortunately I tried running the command `sudo mongod --bind_ip_all` but this did not improve the situation. I wonder if you have any other ideas. Thanks.